# "Can't call method "dir_path" on an undefined value" when running Mason component on the command line

Tags: perl, unit-testing, apache, command-line, mason

Greetings,

I'm trying to develop some tests for Mason components which requires running them on the command line instead of the web server. When I try this, I get an error:

```
perl -MHTML::Mason::Request -MHTML::Mason::Interp -I./lib \
-e '$int = HTML::Mason::Interp->new( data_dir => "/home/friedo/cache", comp_root => "/home/friedo/comps" ); $m = HTML::Mason::Request->new( comp => "/dummy", interp => $int ); $m->comp("/dummy")'
```

Results in:

```
Can't call method "dir_path" on an undefined value at lib/HTML/Mason/Request.pm line 1123.
```

The error is thrown when the call to `->comp` is attempted. I can't figure out what's wrong with the configuration. The component is there and appears to be compiled just fine, and it works via Apache.

This is using HTML::Mason 1.35.

**Edit**: Let's try a bounty for this one. The alternative is me having to dive deep into Mason's guts! :)

**Edit again**: Thanks very much to [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142640/david) for pointing out the crucial detail that I missed for getting this to work.

This was actually for a test framework that needed to exercise a module that calls some Mason comps -- under normal operation the module is provided with a Mason request object to use for that purpose, but I couldn't get that to work offline. The key was using an Interpreter object instead, so I ended up doing the following, which is a little silly but makes the tests work:

```
sub _mason_out { 
   ...
   my $buf;
   if ( $ENV{MASON_TEST} ) { 
       my $int = HTML::Mason::Interp->new( comp_root  => $self->{env}->comp_dir,
                                           out_method => \$buf );

       $int->exec( $comp, %args );
   } else { 
       my $m = $self->{mason_object};
       $m->comp( { store => \$buf }, $comp, %args );
   }

   return $buf;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this fails because your Request object hasn't built a component stack at the point that it is called. Use the `Interp->exec()` method instead as described in [Using Mason from a Standalone Script](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/HTML-Mason-1.42/lib/HTML/Mason/Admin.pod#Using_Mason_from_a_Standalone_Script)

```
perl -MHTML::Mason::Interp -I./lib \
-e 'HTML::Mason::Interp->new( data_dir => "/home/friedo/cache", comp_root => "/home/friedo/comps" )->exec("/dummy")'
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the missing piece of the puzzle that I somehow overlooked in the docs. +200 for you. Also updated the question with some details about the bigger picture.